# nginx error_page configuration

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-403

I am new to nginx server, 
i am trying to validate all request through auth_request module it is working as expected, but in error page configuration it is not working,
I have 2 error page configuration 1 for 401 and 1 for 403

```
    error_page 401 = @error401;
    location @error401 {
        return 302 /login?state=secure;
    }
   error_page 403 =@error403;
    location = @error403 {
       return 302 /accessDenied;
   }
```

but when server return 401 it is working perfectly,
and when server return 403 then it show default 403 page, i wanted it to land on /accessDenied page.
can you please help!!!

Comment: Your `error_page 403` is missing a space!!

Comment: Thanks Richard, i tried with space also but no luck

Answer (score 1):

I do not have the reputation to comment. The location line for the 403 should not have an equals sign.

i.e. `location = @error403 {` should be `location @error403 {`

The syntax for the commands you are using and how to use them (although your usage seems fine) are well summarised here, http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html